# Javascript RegEx build for a phone number validation

Tags: javascript

I need a regex for phone number validation. But I could not build it. Could you please help me out by giving me just the regex?

The phone number structure should be like this:

1. **First:** Optional **+** sign, Optional **space**, 1-3 digits
2. **Then:** Optional space
3. **Then:** Optional (, optional space, 1-3 digits, optional space, )
4. **Then:** Optional space or dash (minus) "-"
5. **Then:** At least 5 digits separated with optional one-character separators. Separators are dash ("-"), or space (" ")
6. Illegal anywhere in the string: **-(**, **)-**, **--**, "  " (2 spaces)

Comment: It's very odd that you would open with a `+`, allowing international phone numbers, and then demand specific formatting which doesn't match the phone number conventions of the country I live in.

Comment: @Quentin One of my US friend gave me that assignment. He wants it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close to your specifications:

```
/^\+?\s?[0-9]{1,3}\s?([0-9]{1,3})?[\s-]?([0-9][\s-]){5}([0-9][\s-])*$/
```

Note that:

- This is untested, and I'm not particularly skilled with regex, so I may well have missed something, but this should get you on your way.
- The format you asked for seems extremely unusual for a phone number, but I tried to implement your requested format regardless.
- At least one of your criteria is unmet by the above expression. (After the 2nd set of digits, you asked to permit a space followed by a hyphen, but my expression would only allow for one or the other. I wasn't sure how to solve this exactly, but I hope you'll be a lot closer to a working solution with this than you were before.)

Here's an explanation of what's going on with individual characters:

- The ^ and $ characters indicate the beginning and end of a field, respectively.
- The \s means a whitespace character (which can also be characters like tab or return.)
- The \d is any digit.
- The + makes a "+". (You need the "\" here because "+" is a special character.)

...and with "modifying" characters and groups:

- A question mark (?) makes the thing before it optional (Must be zero or one occurrence.)
- An asterisk (*) makes the thing before it optional (Can be any number of occurrences.)
- Parentheses create groups, so when you see a question mark, for example, after a closing parenthesis, everything between the parentheses is optional.
- Curly braces mean repetition, so the {1,3} means the thing before it can occur 1 to 3 times.
- Square brackets offer choices, so the [\s-] means a whitespace character or a hyphen.

You'll get a much better understanding of regex after a few minutes checking out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions